# Boost::Spirit::Lex; How do I specify the token "||"?

Tags: c++, regex, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-lex

So my question is quite simple, in my lexer class (extending `lex::lexer<T>`), I have the following;

```
this->self.add
    ...
    ("&&", AND_AND)
    ("||", OR_OR)
    ...
```

Inside my constructor, which compiles just fine, but triggers a SegFault on runtime. The issue is quite obvious `|` is the 'or' operator in the regex system, how do I get past this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/lex/quick_reference/lexer.html

> ```
> \X
> ```
>
> If X is a, b, e, n, r, f, t, v then the ANSI-C interpretation of \x. Otherwise a literal X (used to escape operators such as *)

So you would use

```
 ("\\|\\|", OR_OR)
```

The first backslash in each pair is treated as an escape character by the C++ string parser, causing the second one to be placed into the string content.  That backslash in the string content then is seen by Spirit::Lex and acts to escape the regex operator.

Comment: Oh wow, I was looking at the exact same page, not seeing this.. Must be getting late. Anyway, thanks! Accepting!